# Cognos - List report (Relational database) - Summary limitations

Tags: cognos

I have a Cognos report with Data like so.

`User    Units   TimeInHours  UnitsPerHour
Smith    10      1            10
Smith    30      2            15`

In my report I group by user.  I can do a total on Units and Hours, but how can i summarize units per hour?

Its not the average 10+15/2 = 12.5,

its (10+30)/(1+2) = 13.33

In my report, UnitsPerHour is a calculation.  It's just Units divided by hours.

I don't really need to summarize my unitsPerHour column at all.  I need to perform a calculation based on my summary of other columns, but that appears to be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build it yourself if you don't want to total the other columns.  Add a query calculation in your footer.  It will be `total(Units for report) / total(TimeinHours for report).`

Comment: It was that simple.  Not sure why I didn't expect that to work.  Thanks,  =)